# How to send an array using MPI

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I am trying to send an array using MPI from a slave to a master, and then do something with the output. I can send and recieve an integer, however when i try to do so with an array, it does not work. Ive tried including and not including the pointer & when sending the array using MPI_Send and MPI_Recieve. Cannot get anything.

Below is a sample code i have been working with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"
main(int argc, char **argv ) {
    char message[20];
    int i,j, ressize, out, numprocs, myid, proc, res[10];
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            if(myid == 0)
            {
                for (proc = 0; proc < numprocs; proc++)
                {
                    MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, proc, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }

                for (proc = 1; proc < numprocs; proc++)
                {
                    MPI_Recv(res, sizeof(res), MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
                        printf("result = %i\n",res[j]);
                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                MPI_Recv(&i, 1 , MPI_INT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                for(j=0;j<10;j++){
                    res[j]=i+10;
                    printf("j= %i, res= %i\n",j,i+10);
                }
                ressize = sizeof(res);
                MPI_Send(res, ressize, MPI_INT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
    MPI_Finalize();
    }
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Please show us a _complete program_ that exhibits the failure, that we can compile and run and experiment with.  (Your fragment appears to be for the single-int case?)  Please also be much more specific about the "does not work" part.  We need you to describe, in detail, exactly what you expected to happen _and_ what happened instead.

Comment: Basically when I calculate the values for the array, it is fine but when i send using MPI_Send, and then recieve using MPI_Recieve, I am getting different data and not sure why. Im expecting to get just the array i sent and be able to manipulate it as i please, however, I am getting an array of different values not sure where the are coming from. What would be best way to share full code? when i went to add it when writing question, it didnt consider the initial declaration code so i left them out.

Comment: `sizeof(res)` in the `MPI_Send` call and `sizeof(res)` in the `MPI_Recv` call should be the **number of elements** of `res`, not the total size in bytes. In your case that would probably be `10`.

Comment: Changing it to 10 managed to fix it. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Note that you can get the number of elements in an array as `sizeof(res)/sizeof(res[0])`, or `#define RES_ELEMS 10U`.